# Azure Data Factory - Google Big Query as source in "Copy Task" - error message: 'GHighThroughputApiError'?

Tags: azure, google-bigquery, odbc, azure-data-factory, copy-data

We are encountering a problem with copying/receiving data from Google BigQuery in a job in Azure Data Factory.

A pipeline containing Google BigQuery as source randomly fails with the following error:

**Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DSI] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the error message for key 'GHighThroughputApiError' with message parameters ['Error : { code: UNKNOWN, message: Stream removed }'] and component ID 100: Message not found in file "D:\batch\tasks\shared\ODBC Drivers\Microsoft Google BigQuery ODBC Driver_2.4.5.1014\lib.. \ErrorMessages\en-US\SimbaBigQueryODBCMessages.xml",Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DSI] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the error message for key 'GHighThroughputApiError' with message parameters ['Error: { code: UNKNOWN, message: Stream removed }'] and component ID 100: Message not found in file "D:\batch\tasks\ shared\ODBC Drivers\Microsoft Google BigQuery ODBC Driver_2.4.5.1014\lib..\ErrorMessages\en-US\SimbaBigQueryODBCMessages.xml",Source=Microsoft ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery,'**

This error, for example, does not appear after restarting the task, e.g. after 30 seconds.

Is there any solution to this problem?

We tried to use our own SelfHosted Integration Runtime with the latest version of ODBC Simba, but the situation is the same.